# can I download DESeq2 in R 3.6.3 in Linux MInt?

Tags: r, rna-seq

I am trying to download DESeq2 in R 3.6.3. Is it possible?
This is printed when I am trying: Warning in install.packages : package ‘DESeq2’ is not available (for R version 3.6.3)
Thank you!

Comment: You might have more luck using conda to look for older versions of the DESeq2 package that are compatible with R 3.6.3. If not, you can use conda to install compatible versions of R and DESeq2 in a new environment and use that environment for your analyses.

Answer (score 1):

[Bioconductor](https://bioconductor.org/) is a package management tool for R that allows you to install the appropriate package versions for your R version.

For R 3.6.3 you'll need Bioconductor 3.10:

```
if (!requireNamespace("BiocManager", quietly = TRUE))
    install.packages("BiocManager")
BiocManager::install(version = "3.10")
```

Then you install  DESeq2:

```
BiocManager::install("DESeq2")
```

Answer (score 0):

these errors are generated when I am doing what PPK suggested:
Bioconductor version 3.10 (BiocManager 1.30.10), R 3.6.3
(2020-02-29)
Installation path not writeable, unable to update packages: nlme,
spatial, survival

> BiocManager::install("DESeq2")
> Bioconductor version 3.10 (BiocManager 1.30.10), R 3.6.3
> (2020-02-29)
> Installing package(s) 'DESeq2'
> Warning: dependency ‘XML’ is not available
> also installing the dependencies ‘annotate’, ‘genefilter’, ‘geneplotter’

## trying URL 'https://bioconductor.org/packages/3.10/bioc/src/contrib/annotate_1.64.0.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 1873132 bytes (1.8 MB)

downloaded 1.8 MB

## trying URL 'https://bioconductor.org/packages/3.10/bioc/src/contrib/genefilter_1.68.0.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 1421076 bytes (1.4 MB)

downloaded 1.4 MB

## trying URL 'https://bioconductor.org/packages/3.10/bioc/src/contrib/geneplotter_1.64.0.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 1431450 bytes (1.4 MB)

downloaded 1.4 MB

## trying URL 'https://bioconductor.org/packages/3.10/bioc/src/contrib/DESeq2_1.26.0.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 2060061 bytes (2.0 MB)

downloaded 2.0 MB

ERROR: dependency ‘XML’ is not available for package ‘annotate’

- removing ‘/home/nikolena/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.6/annotate’
  ERROR: dependency ‘annotate’ is not available for package ‘genefilter’
- removing ‘/home/nikolena/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.6/genefilter’
  ERROR: dependency ‘annotate’ is not available for package ‘geneplotter’
- removing ‘/home/nikolena/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.6/geneplotter’
  ERROR: dependencies ‘genefilter’, ‘geneplotter’ are not available for package ‘DESeq2’
- removing ‘/home/nikolena/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.6/DESeq2’

The downloaded source packages are in
‘/tmp/RtmphLXrZb/downloaded_packages’
Installation path not writeable, unable to update packages: nlme,
spatial, survival
Warning messages:
1: In install.packages(...) :
installation of package ‘annotate’ had non-zero exit status
2: In install.packages(...) :
installation of package ‘genefilter’ had non-zero exit status
3: In install.packages(...) :
installation of package ‘geneplotter’ had non-zero exit status
4: In install.packages(...) :
installation of package ‘DESeq2’ had non-zero exit status

I have tried to instal XML and the other dependencies without success..